# Compare Fabric App Distribution and the Google Play Store Test Channel?

Tags: android, testing

What reason would I use Fabric App Distribution instead of the Google Play Store Test Channel to deploy my Android app to testers, if I will not be using it for the equivalent iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play require versionCode to be changed every time you upload an application.